# Order column with integers separated by "-" in R

Tags: r

I would like to order a column containing characters like this:

```
K3SG1-105-1051-1
```

However, using the arrange function will result in this:

```
K3SG1-105-1051-1

K3SG1-105-1051-10

K3SG1-105-1051-100

K3SG1-105-1051-1000
```

Instead of what I want:

```
K3SG1-105-1051-1

K3SG1-105-1051-2

K3SG1-105-1051-3

K3SG1-105-1051-4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility using `tidyr::separate` and `dplyr`:

```
# Sample data
df <- data.frame(id = paste0("K3SG1-105-1051-", seq(1:10)));

# Using separate
df %>%
    separate(id, into = paste0("id", 1:4), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>%
    arrange(as.numeric(id4)) %>%
    select(id);
#                  id
#1   K3SG1-105-1051-1
#2   K3SG1-105-1051-2
#3   K3SG1-105-1051-3
#4   K3SG1-105-1051-4
#5   K3SG1-105-1051-5
#6   K3SG1-105-1051-6
#7   K3SG1-105-1051-7
#8   K3SG1-105-1051-8
#9   K3SG1-105-1051-9
#10 K3SG1-105-1051-10
```

Explanation: Split column `id` into four separate columns based on `"-"` as separator; `arrange` rows based on the fourth column entries, which are converted to `numeric` to ensure proper ordering.

Answer (score 0):

#### Data

I created the following example data for this answer:

```
(char_vec <- paste0("K3SG1-105-1051-", c(1:4, 10, 100, 1000)))

[1] "K3SG1-105-1051-1"    "K3SG1-105-1051-2"    "K3SG1-105-1051-3"   
[4] "K3SG1-105-1051-4"    "K3SG1-105-1051-10"   "K3SG1-105-1051-100" 
[7] "K3SG1-105-1051-1000"
```

#### Solution

```
char_vec[order(as.numeric(sub('.*-', '', char_vec)))]

[1] "K3SG1-105-1051-1"    "K3SG1-105-1051-2"    "K3SG1-105-1051-3"   
[4] "K3SG1-105-1051-4"    "K3SG1-105-1051-10"   "K3SG1-105-1051-100" 
[7] "K3SG1-105-1051-1000"
```

#### Explanation

`sub('.*-', '', char_vec)` gets just the last number characters in the vector, which we then convert to numeric and order to order `char_vec`.

If you order the **characters** 1, 2, and 10, the order is 1, 10, 2 because you're alphabetically ordering strings, not ordering numbers.